# Where is this "text.txt" file stored?How would I change where the file is saved to and view the contents?

Tags: java, android, filepath

I followed a tutorial to create this code, after searching and searching for the "text.txt" file, I can't find it anywhere! Am I missing something? How can I change where the file is stored?

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/msg"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:ems="10"
     android:hint="Enter a message"
      >
      <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/LOAD"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SAVE"
      android:layout_below="@+id/SAVE"
      android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
      android:text="LOAD DATA" />
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/SAVE"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
      android:text="SAVE DATA" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.conor.filedemo;
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.FileInputStream;
      import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.io.FileOutputStream;
      import java.io.FileReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;
      import java.io.*;
      import java.util.*;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       Button save,load;
       EditText message;
       String Message;
       int data_block = 100;



       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SAVE);
                load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LOAD);
                message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
                save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {

                                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  Message = message.getText().toString();
                                  try {
                                           FileOutputStream fou = openFileOutput("text.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                                           OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
                                           try {
                                                    osw.write(Message);
                                                    osw.flush();
                                                    osw.close();
                                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                              }
                                      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                      }
                             }
                    });
                load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             try {
                                      FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("text.txt");
                                      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                                      char[] data = new char[data_block];
                                      String final_data="";
                                      int size;
                                      try {
                                               while((size = isr.read(data))>0)
                                                  {
                                                   String read_data = String.copyValueOf(data, 0, size);
                                                   final_data+= read_data;
                                                   data = new char[data_block];
                                                   }
                                               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Message :"+final_data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                          } catch (IOException e) {
                                               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                               e.printStackTrace();
                                          }
                                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                             }
                    });
           }
       //@Override
       //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       //         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //        return true;
        //   }
  }
```

Comment: the method `openFileOutput` create file in File Directory pf Your application package folder. Like, ` /data/data/<YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME>/Files`.

Comment: @qcGold - on the contrary, this code creates the file!

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are generating an output file named text.txt from a byte stream.

```
FileOutputStream fou = openFileOutput("text.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
```

You can simply change the name or directory of where the file is saved. Refer to [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) for an idea of how to change the directory to your liking.

However, be sure that you change your input stream as well:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("text.txt");
```

I would suggest creating a File object with the name of the file just to avoid any errors.

```
File f = new File("text.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops my first several responses were incorrect.  Do the following to create a file in your application directory.

```
String homeDirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                        "/" + getPackageName();
File homeDir = new File(homeDirName);
if (!homeDir.exists())
    homeDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(homeDir, "text.txt");
FileOutputStream fou = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

You will need to add the following permission line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On your Android device, look for common directories like 'DCIM', 'Download', 'Alarms', etc.  Your application directory will be in that directory and will be the package name you used. To find your package name, look in your AndroidManifest.xml file for something like

```
package="com.xyz.pgmname".
```

Comment: No.  The directories you speak of are on the External Storage.  In contrast, the openFileOutput() method of Context writes to and if necessary creates a file on the Internal Storage.  Although this file is set by the poster's code to be world readable, its location will not be *browsable* except on an emulator or engineering/hacked device where adb runs as root.

Comment: Getting closer, but don't assume that the directory you want to write to already exists.

Comment: Tnx again.   So pls tell me, when is it necessary to create an empty file using file.createNewFile()  ??  Seems to work without it.

Comment: It's not.  The FileOutputStream constructor will create the file if needed.  What you had been missing before was the mkdirs() call, which you've now added.